# What is the difference between 'at a conference' and 'in conference'?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, articles

Here's how the Longman dictionary distinguishes the two senses of the noun 'conference'.

> 1 a large formal meeting where a lot of people discuss important matters such as business, politics, or science, especially for several days *[for this sense, I assume, it's '**at** a conference']*
>
> [...]
>
> 2 a private meeting for a few people to have formal discussions
>
> [...]
>
> Mr Dickson is **in** conference.

*(from [here](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/conference))*

I find this distinction quite subtle and hardly significant at all. Please explain the difference in usage. In addition, I have no idea why there's no article in the second example given the fact that it's a countable noun. Even my spellchecker Grammarly objects.

Comment: If you're *at a conference*, you could simply be an observer of an event; but if you're *in conference*, you're an actual participant in a discussion.

Comment: @JasonBassfordSupportsMonica What do you think of Kate's answer?

Comment: That answer is pretty much what I said in my comment, just phrased differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) refers to a conference as an organised event - "International Conference on XYZ"

(2) refers to Mr Dickson being one of a group of people *conferring* together; it might be part of a larger event, or just a situation where local officials have come together to discuss some serious issue that has arisen.